# how can I show Arabic Unicode from Mysql database to my Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

how can I show Arabic Unicode from Mysql database to my Android app.

### I setup utf8_unicode_ci to all my tables and utf8_general_ci to my database, it shows Arabic in mysql but it just show ????? when browsing in my Android App and Postman.

Any one has a solution for this issue.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

check this out:

```
newString = new String(yourString.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8");
```

I hope to be useful ;)